# [Exception Occurred: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070296): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070296

Tags: windows-container, comexception, perfview

When I'm running prefview tool (https://github.com/microsoft/perfview) in the windows container, I encounter this exception:

```
[Exception Occurred: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070296): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070296
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Extensions.ETWControl.EnableStackCaching(UInt64 traceHandle)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session.TraceEventSession.EnableKernelProvider(Keywords flags, Keywords stackCapture)
   at PerfView.CommandProcessor.Start(CommandLineArgs parsedArgs)
   at PerfView.CommandProcessor.Collect(CommandLineArgs parsedArgs)
   at PerfView.CommandProcessor.ExecuteCommand(CommandLineArgs parsedArgs)]
```

Here is my usage:

1. Download the latest prefview from:  https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/releases/download/v3.0.6/PerfView.exe
2. Copy the `PerfView.exe` into the windows container
3. use `crictl exec <contianer id> powershell`  command to open a Powershell in the container
4. Running the command

```
.\PerfView "/DataFile:PerfViewData.etl" /BufferSizeMB:256 /StackCompression /CircularMB:500 /logFile=log.txt /maxCollectSec=30 /NoGui collect
```

My windows container's base image is: `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809`

My isolation runtime is:   `runhcs-wcow-hypervisor`

Anything I can do about it? Thanks in advance.

I have read this post: https://githublab.com/repository/issues/microsoft/perfview/1601. It said that we should use hyper-v isolation and that's exactly what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Server Core image? It might be the case that PerfView is trying to access OS APIs that are not present in Nano Server.

Comment: Yes, we have tried different image using docker:

`docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803 powershell`

Also encounter this problem.
Currently we can only add parameter `/KernelEvents:Profile` to omit some kernel info. But it lost many details in Flame Graph, so I still want to remove this parameter when I collect PerfView.

Comment: It does seems to me that the tool is trying to access something that is not present. First, this image of Server Core is very old and not supported anymore. I'd try with the 1809/ltsc2019 (which are the same), or the ltsc2022. Also, you might want to try with the Windows or Server image as they have the largest set of APIs available.

Comment: A larger image may cause overhead to my service, but I will try them. Thanks a lot for your answer.